# Directory not found for option! ios

Tags: ios, dependencies, linker-errors

So our iOS project has been shared amongst our team and I guess some of our files, such as library files, png files, and just some folders have been "lost" over the sharing process.

That being said, our code is performing the way we like, but there are several warnings stating "directory not found for option".

How can we deal with these warnings without breaking our code?